# How to create a sharp and large edged bordered vertical timeline using tikz-pgf?

Tags: tikz-pgf, timeline

[image]

I wanted to re-create the above timeline using the starter code but I have no idea how to edit colors, remove the left hand side bar that renders from the code below.

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3.141592mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 1mm and 3mm,
  start chain = A going below,
   dot/.style = {circle, draw=white, very thick, fill=gray,
                 minimum size=3mm},
   box/.style = {rectangle, text width=62mm,
                 inner xsep=4mm, inner ysep=1mm,
                 font=\sffamily\small\linespread{0.84}\selectfont,
                 on chain},
                        ]
    \begin{scope}[every node/.append style={box}]
\node { From september 2010 to september 2013   \\      % A-1
        \textcolor{gray}{Industrial design}     \\
        Universidad Antonio de Nebrija, Madrid} ;
\node { From september 2010 to september 2013   \\
        \textcolor{gray}{Industrial design}     \\
        Universidad Antonio de Nebrija, Madrid} ;
\node { From september 2010 to september 2013   \\      % A-3
        \textcolor{gray}{Industrial design}     \\
        Universidad Antonio de Nebrija, Madrid} ;
    \end{scope}
\draw[very thick, gray, {Triangle[length=4pt)]}-{Circle[length=3pt]},
      shorten <=-3mm, shorten >=-3mm]           % <--- here is adjusted additional arrow's 
    (A-1.north west) -- (A-3.south west);
\foreach \i [ count=\j] in {2013,2010,2006}
    \node[dot,label=left:\i] at (A-\j.west) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you image is not entirely clear-- hope the explanation below will help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the code you have shown is in three parts

part 1 is the text on the right of the timeline

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3.141592mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 1mm and 3mm,
  start chain = A going below,
   dot/.style = {circle, draw=white, very thick, fill=gray,
                 minimum size=3mm},
   box/.style = {rectangle, text width=62mm,
                 inner xsep=4mm, inner ysep=1mm,
                 font=\sffamily\small\linespread{0.84}\selectfont,
                 on chain},
                        ]
    \begin{scope}[every node/.append style={box}]
\node { From september 2010 to september 2013   \\      % A-1
        \textcolor{gray}{Industrial design}     \\
        Universidad Antonio de Nebrija, Madrid} ;
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which results in

[image]

this node is auto named as A-1 -- you can change it to B, C etc by changing the code

```
start chain = B going below,
```

similarly the remaining part of the nodes A-2, A-3 are converted to text on the right side of the timeline with the code

```
    \begin{scope}[every node/.append style={box}]
\node { From september 2010 to september 2013   \\      % A-1
        \textcolor{gray}{Industrial design}     \\
        Universidad Antonio de Nebrija, Madrid} ;
\node { From september 2010 to september 2013   \\
        \textcolor{gray}{Industrial design}     \\
        Universidad Antonio de Nebrija, Madrid} ;
\node { From september 2010 to september 2013   \\      % A-3
        \textcolor{gray}{Industrial design}     \\
        Universidad Antonio de Nebrija, Madrid} ;
    \end{scope}
```

which results in

[image]

the second part of the code draws the vertical arrow

```
\draw[very thick, gray, {Triangle[length=4pt)]}-{Circle[length=3pt]},
      shorten <=-3mm, shorten >=-3mm]           % <--- here is adjusted additional arrow's 
    (A-1.north west) -- (A-3.south west);
```

which results in

[image]

the third part of the code draws three circles with the help of the code

```
 \foreach \i [ count=\j] in {2013,2010,2006}
    \node[dot,label=left:\i] at (A-\j.west) {};
```

the three circles result from the operative part of the code

```
[ count=\j] in {2013,2010,2006}
```

then the three circles are given labels on the left side from the code

```
\node[dot,label=left:\i] at (A-\j.west) {};
```

where the `\i is generated as 2006, 2010 and 2013`

and the labels are generated at `label=left:\i` that is `left of 2006, 2010 and 2013`

the three circles are placed at `(A-\j.west)` which converts to `A-1.west, A-2.west and A-3.west`

thus the entire code results in the timeline

[image]

changing the circle style is done with

```
 dot/.style = {circle, draw=white, very thick, fill=gray,
                 minimum size=3mm},
```

for eg if you omit white in `draw=white` and simply write

```
 dot/.style = {circle, draw=blue, very thick, fill=gray,
                 minimum size=3mm},
```

this results in

[image]

or change the `fill=gray`

```
 dot/.style = {circle, draw=blue, very thick, fill=blue!20,
                 minimum size=3mm},
```

this results in

[image]

hope this helps in bringing some clarity on how to proceed